# Concatenate files with prefix

Tags: bash, shell

Assume a folder with files named like this:

```
FOO.1
FOO.2
...
BAR-1.1
BAR-1.2
...
BAR-2.1
BAR-2.2
...
```

And I would like to concatenate them such that it results in 3 files:

```
FOO (consisting of FOO.1 + FOO.2 + FOO.N)
BAR-1 (consisting of BAR-1.1 + BAR-1.2 + BAR-1.N)
BAR-2 (consisting of BAR-2.1 + BAR-2.2 + BAR-2.N)
```

How would this be done in bash/shell script? Assume all the files are in one folder (no need to go into subfolders)

Requires not knowing the filename prefixes in advance

Answer (score 1):

```
for file in *.*
do
  prefix="${file%.*}"
  echo "Adding $file to $prefix ..."
  cat "$file" >> "$prefix"
done
```

Answer (score 0):

```
for i in  $(ls | sed  's/\(.*\)\..$/\1/' | sort -u)
do
  cat $i* > $i
done
```

Comment: Requires not knowing the filename prefixes in advance - edited above to reflect that